# Suggestion for new Vote to Close Reason: Shopping recommendation

Tags: feature-request, close-reasons, vote-to-close

Now, a good number of questions I get around to closing are obvious shopping questions, and tend to be closed off topic when I do.

Considering shopping questions are a definite no-no, could we have 'shopping question' as a reason for vote to close? This (hopefully) would make it a little more obvious.

Comment: I don't agree either, just close them as being off-topic...

Answer (score 8):

No simply flag them for moderation attention and waste as many or your votes on them to get them closed. That should be enough to have them dealt with

Comment: Oh, come on - why not have a proper tag for that? Sometimes it is not clear to the asker that he asked for a shopping recommendation - see http://meta.superuser.com/questions/4427/question-is-closed-without-proper-reason. After all, I can ask "how do you list files in Unix terminal" - and then, even mentioning `ls` in response to that would be a "product recommendation", would it not? I get totally put off when I get close votes as "off-topic"; then I reread the FAQ, and I simply cannot see where I went wrong - and the "dealt with" attitude doesn't help me with that at all.

Answer (score 8):

The "Off Topic" and "Too Localized" close reasons fit shopping questions already.  I think those cover the shopping questions just fine and the FAQ explains in more detail.

And like Ivo mentioned, just flag them.  With the new moderator additions to Super User, flags are dealt with even quicker than before.

Comment: And they get more flags if their flag weight goes up, so they can go crazy on flagging crap!

Comment: @Ivo: But... but... I'm at flag weight 597.8140 already...

Answer (score 3):

> This (hopefully) would make it a little more obvious.

Comments are often left for this purpose, it should be clear to the user. I don't see them complaining...

Comment: Most closevoters are "hit and run", and they can't be bothered to explain what their problem is in comments - and getting just an "Off topic" rarely helps me discover where I went wrong. So I'd correct that to: comments _might_ be left for that purpose, but usually are not.